# STRIPE API Returns Empty Response

Tags: stripe-payments

I am using Sripe PHP SDK from this [link](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php)

When I am trying to use any api of Stripe Payment it gets successful but the response it returns is empty

I am following API Instructions from [Strip API Documentations](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents)

For example I am using following code snippet to create a payment

```
    $stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient(
      'SECRET_KEY'
    );
    
    
    $stripe->paymentIntents->create([
      'amount' => 1200,
      'currency' => 'usd',
      'payment_method_types' => ['card']
    ]);
         
   // after successfull payment, you can store payment related information into your database
 $this->response([ 'success' =>'1' ,'status' => 'success', 'message' => $stripe], REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);
```

But it is not returning any response, instead the return object is empty.

Here is the response

```
{"success":"1","status":"success","message":{}}
```

It should return an object like this in message

```
{
  "id": "pi_1HkSRrKUkp6sNA1QWNFwUOLd",
  "object": "payment_intent",
  "amount": 2000,
  "amount_capturable": 0,
  "amount_received": 0,
  "application": null,
  "application_fee_amount": null,
  "canceled_at": null,
  "cancellation_reason": null,
  "capture_method": "automatic",
  "charges": {
    "object": "list",
    "data": [],
    "has_more": false,
    "url": "/v1/charges?payment_intent=pi_1HkSRrKUkp6sNA1QWNFwUOLd"
  },
  "client_secret": "SECRET_KEY",
  "confirmation_method": "automatic",
  "created": 1604659539,
  "currency": "usd",
  "customer": null,
  "description": "Created by stripe.com/docs demo",
  "invoice": null,
  "last_payment_error": null,
  "livemode": false,
  "metadata": {},
  "next_action": null,
  "on_behalf_of": null,
  "payment_method": null,
  "payment_method_options": {
    "card": {
      "installments": null,
      "network": null,
      "request_three_d_secure": "automatic"
    }
  },
  "payment_method_types": [
    "card"
  ],
  "receipt_email": null,
  "review": null,
  "setup_future_usage": null,
  "shipping": null,
  "statement_descriptor": null,
  "statement_descriptor_suffix": null,
  "status": "requires_payment_method",
  "transfer_data": null,
  "transfer_group": null
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where exactly are you getting that example from? It looks incomplete.

You should just save the output of the API call to some variable, then return the `client_secret` [for example](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?integration=elements#web-create-payment-intent):

```
$intent = $stripe->paymentIntents->create([
  'amount' => 1200,
  'currency' => 'usd',
  'payment_method_types' => ['card']
]);

$this->response([ 'success' =>'1' ,'status' => 'success', 'message' => $intent->client_secret], REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);
```